# Powershell script triggers process only when invoked manually. Timing out when triggered via Scheduled Task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, powershell-4.0

On a Windows 2012 R2 server there is a Powershell script that I can manually invoke to start a process on some EXE, this works just fine.

But when trying to trigger it via a scheduled task (invoking the same script) the `start-process` within the script just doesn't trigger or finish. Causing the task scheduler to terminate the task due to exceeding the timeout threshold.

Here's the core section of the script:

```js
$exe = "c:\some\app.exe"
$arguments = "-user me -pwd secret"
$process = Start-Process $exe -ArgumentList $arguments -PassThru -Wait
return $process
```

Is there some way I can get some insights into what `start-process` is doing or why the same script works when invoked manually but not programmatically?

I want to emphasize that the way the script is invoked from the scheduled task is not a problem! The script triggers because the corresponding log file populates.

Any insights or help on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick update on this since I found the problem. It turns out, it had nothing to do with either the powershell script or the scheduled task itself...

On the machine the script is running on, there is a network share that is mapped as the `z:\` drive. I use it to save logs to. Now apparently that mapping/mounting is handled differently depending on whether the script is invoked interactively or programatically, because in the latter case it appears that the resoultion of the network path `\\network\share\folder1` does not succeed, however there is nothing complaining about it, the process just silently does not start. If however, I point the logs to a physical local path or the explicit full network path itself, there is no problem running the script.

Lesson learned, never trust OS' drive mapping of network paths :D

Cheers